# How do I scroll to a position programmatically in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I have a scroll view which scrolls horizontally. I just added images, labels and a webview in it and there are many objects in it. 
I want to directly scroll to the first object in the scroll view.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 91):

Use the following code:

```
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
```

Comment: scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);

Comment: Use [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES] if you want animation.

Answer (score 48):

To animate your scrolling do this:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 768, 1024, 748); //wherever you want to scroll 
[self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
```

Comment: Is there a way where you wouldn't have to specify width and height of the scroll view?

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way with animation ->

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES]
```

Answer (score 1):

The swift 3 version of the answer is:

`scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)`

Answer (score 0):

If someone wonder how to do it in Swift 5 with xcode 11:

I put negative value in the x parameters becouse I want to scroll to left

```
let frame = CGRect(x: -540, y: 0, width: 1080, height: 370); //wherever you want to scroll
boardScrollView.scrollRectToVisible(frame, animated: true) // set animated to true if you want to animate it
```

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 350.0), animated: true)
    }
```